# Exporting MySQL database

Tags: phpmyadmin, spreadsheet, mysql

When exporting from MySQL database (through phpMyAdmin) how can one create a spreadsheet that recognises the SQL delineation to correctly maintain the database columns?

For instance, when exporting to CSV format for excel, all columns from the database are squashed into a single column in the excel sheet

> A1 = id;"fname";"sname";"email";"phone";"dob"; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your data as CSV. Make sure "Fields terminated by" is set to "," (comma). Yours look like they may be set to ";" (semicolon). As a result, Excel does not recognize your field separators and thinks an entire row is all one field.

Also, you may want to "Put field names in the first row" to retain your column headers.

Comment: Perfect - CSV export designed for excel lacks these parameters, but default CSV export has these - and is easily interpreted by excel! :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE syntax` for the delination you desire. To add column names you can try the following as well..

```
SELECT col1, col2.... UNION
SELECT col1, col2... FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE "c:/mycsv.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

Once this is done, in Excel you will have to do the either tab/comma/; delimitted `Text-To-Columns` via menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your fields are separated by semi-colons not commas (you can change this in PHPMyAdmin settings when exporting for the delimiter to be a `,`).

If you can't re-export, a workaround is to change the file type to .txt, open it in excel and specify the delimiters manually when the import wizard comes up.